# Pine script indicator undesired chart scaling

Tags: pine-script

I coded indicator that creates monthly/weekly/daily even on lower time frames based on the information from higher time frames.

This levels can be created far back in the history. What annoys me that when analysing chart on lower time frame, I don't want to see monthly level from way back. TradingView wants to show me all the lines from my indicator and squashes candles to fit all data.

Is there a way to disable this auto scaling? I just want bars to be show at the exact same scale as if there would be no lines created by my indicator. If lines would be in view they would be shown otherwise they are out of visible space but still there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set `scaling=scaling.none` or disable the auto scaling yourself.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)
plot(100000)
plot(0)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this already, but it didn't work. Now I found out that I had to remove and re-add the indicator for this property to take effect. Thank you!

Comment: Strange now when scaling is disabled, levels are not on the correct position anymore. https://storage.googleapis.com/openscreenshot/q%2FP%2Ff/xRO9ZtfPq.png

Comment: Yes, you need to re-add the indicator. Can you share your code maybe? Just to be sure that it is not related to your code.

Comment: This problem is really easy to replicate with simple demo code. scale just mean if indicator will be using charts scale or not. Simple code https://pastecode.io/s/zrqr4yqw that shows the issue.

Comment: I changed it to scale.right which creates additional scale on the right and it is obvious that scale for indicator and scale for chart is different https://pastecode.io/s/ia1vbq2q Even more obvious when you zoom in/out the candles (mouse scroll in/out)

Answer (score 0):

Trying enabling the "Scale price chart only" option in the cog wheel menu on the bottom right of the chart.

[image: Picture.]